# rendered imaged looks deformed compared to view port camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I created a scene and set up the camera and everything looks OK in the 
viewport. After I render the result looks different than expected.

See the images below:

1. Camera view render in viewport. That's what I want
2. The result after I hit render.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any compositor node? Did you change the Aspect Ratio fields in the Dimension section of the Render settings? Are you using a particular output format?

Comment: the aspect ratio is not correct.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! and yeah I change the aspect ratio to one by one that's it thank you again bye